# TypeScript Class Inheritance: 'super' Can Only Be Referenced in Members of Derived Classes or Object Literal Expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance, typescript

We're using TypeScript classes with inheritance and have run into an apparent scoping issue. TypeScript/JavaScript is not allowing us to call 'super' from within a promise structure (or even from an enclosed function). We're receiving this error:

**TypeScript: 'super' Can Only Be Referenced in Members of Derived Classes or Object Literal Expressions**

Is there a way around this? Here's the code:

```
export class VendorBill extends Transaction {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    save() {

        let deferred = $.Deferred();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/myrestapi',
            success: function (data) {    
                deferred.resolve();    
            },
            error: function (jqXHR: any, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                deferred.reject()
            }
        })

        $.when(deferred).always(function () {
            super.save();  <----------- THIS IS CAUSING THE ERROR
        })    
    }
}
```

Comment: Also worth pointing out you're using the promise antipattern of using an extra deferred object when you don't need one. You can just do `$.ajax({...}).always(() => { super.save(); });`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that the compiler turns `super.save()` to:

```
_super.prototype.fn.call(this);
```

But `this` isn't the right one because you're passing a function which isn't bound to the right context.

You can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
$.when(deferred).always(() => {
    super.save();
})
```